# Didn't got the odd even linklist

Tags: python, linked-list

i was solving the leetcode problem 328. Odd Even Linked List where we have to print all the number at the odd index first and on the even index.

```
class Node:  
    def __init__(self, data): 
        self.data = data   
        self.next = None

class LinkedList: 
    def __init__(self): 
        self.head = None

    def printList(self): 
        temp = self.head 
        while (temp): 
            print (temp.data) 
            temp = temp.next


    def oddEvenList(self):
        end = Node(self.head)
        temp = Node(self.head)
        #end = head
        #temp = head
        counter = 0

        while end.next is not None:
            end = end.next
            counter += 1 
        if((counter & 1) == 0):
            counter = counter //2
        else:
            counter =  (counter//2) + 1

        while counter != 0:
            end.next = temp.next
            temp.next = temp.next.next
            end.next.next = None
            end = end.next
            temp = temp.next
        return self.head

if __name__=='__main__': 

    # Start with the empty list 
    llist = LinkedList() 

    llist.head = Node(1) 
    second = Node(2) 
    third = Node(3)
    fourth = Node(4)
    fifth = Node(5)

    llist.head.next = second; 
    second.next = third;
    third.next = fourth
    fourth.next = fifth
    fifth.next = None

    llist.printList() 

    llist.oddEvenList()

    llist.printList()
```

the logic is correct and should work as i trace the program many times.

I think the my program doesn't enter in the first while loop.

```
while end.next is not None:
        end = end.next
        counter += 1
```

Can any suggest, is there any syntax mistake which i am missing, otherwise the logic is correct for the program.

Input - 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> Null
above program Output - 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> Null

Desired output - 1 -> 3 -> 5 -> 2 -> 4 -> Null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a ListNode and generate it in simple way

```py
def oddEvenList(self, head):
    dummy1 = odd = ListNode(0)
    dummy2 = even = ListNode(0)
    while head:
        odd.next = head
        even.next = head.next
        odd = odd.next
        even = even.next
        head = head.next.next if even else None
    odd.next = dummy2.next
    return dummy1.next
```

Comment: Hi @Rajan Pipaliya, remember me, add some more details explaining the answer :P.

Comment: Great,  your logic works, but can you please explain the error in mine. @Rajan Pipaliya